# Contact form(PHP) Not working

Tags: php, forms, contacts

The contact form i am using for my site is not working as intended whenever all the information is correctly filled it still produces the error message. Here are both the files i am using.

Greatly appreciate the help.

config.php

```
        <?
    //define the receiver of the email
    define('TO_EMAIL','any@gmail.com');

    //define the subject of the email
    define('SUBJECT','Website Inquiry');    

    // Messages
    define('MSG_INVALID_NAME','Please enter your name.');
    define('MSG_INVALID_EMAIL','Please enter valid e-mail.');
    define('MSG_INVALID_MESSAGE','Please enter your message.');
    define('MSG_SEND_ERROR','Sorry, we can\'t send this message.');

?>
```

contact.php

```
    <?php 

    require_once('config.php');

    // Sender Info
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);
    $err = "";

    // Check Info
    $pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$^";
    if(!preg_match_all($pattern, $email, $out)) {
        $err = MSG_INVALID_EMAIL; // Invalid email
    }
    if(!$email) {
        $err = MSG_INVALID_EMAIL; // No Email
    }   
    if(!$message) {
        $err = MSG_INVALID_MESSAGE; // No Message
    }
    if (!$name) {
        $err = MSG_INVALID_NAME; // No name 
    }

    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\nReply-To: ".$email."";

    if (!$err){

        //send the email
        $sent = mail(TO_EMAIL,SUBJECT,$message,$headers); 

        if ($sent) {
                // If the message is sent successfully print
                echo "SEND"; 
            } else {
                // Display Error Message
                echo MSG_SEND_ERROR; 
            }
    } else {
        echo $err; // Display Error Message
    }
?>
```

HTML FORM -

```
  <!-- Contact Form -->
                <div class="contact-form">
                    <h3 class="main-heading"><span>Let's keep in touch</span></h3>
                    <div id="contact-status"></div>
                    <form action="" id="contactform">
                        <p>
                            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="input" >
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="input">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="message">Your Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" cols="88" rows="6" class="textarea" ></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send your message" class="submit">
                    </form>
```

Comment: [**Errors being?**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - We're not debuggers; that's your job.

Comment: "it still produces the error message"  — What error message?

Comment: Your script is unsafe btw. It allows mail header splitting, i.e., attackers can missuse it for spamming.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Make sure your form elements are named; you haven't posted that. Make sure you can send mail, how many more "Make sure's" do I have to come up with?

Comment: **There's NOTHING wrong with your code, it's YOU.** -1 for not further investigating the problem and wasting everybody's time.

Comment: Use this for the REAL error > `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` placed just beneath your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: there is something wrong because if i fill out the information i get the message 'Sorry, we can\'t send this message.' being called from my config.php even though nothing is wrong..

Comment: You also do not have to be so rude Fred.. I am new to this website..

Comment: The error is that it skips actually sending the mail and heads straight to

    } else {
                // Display Error Message
                echo MSG_SEND_ERROR;

Comment: Did you not add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` like I suggested you do? If so, what are the exact errors? `Sorry, we can\'t send this message` doesn't give you the REAL error. Plus, are you running this from your own computer, a hosted website? Is MAIL available for you to use? The reasons are next to endless.

Comment: Hosted website- and an easy PHP contact form will work as i have tested it. but for some reason this certain code will not work!

Comment: Ok, the only thing I can see that will prevent it from sending, is that your HTML form does not have named form elements. I tested your code without a form using `$_POST['name'] = "Name"; $_POST['email'] = "email@example.com"; $_POST['message'] = "Hello there buddy!";` (to override it) on top of `// Sender Info` and it worked. Make sure your inputs have `<input type="text" name="email">` etc. - Post your form in your question so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Again, did you place `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` below your `<?php` tag? That will/should throw you an error, such as `Undefined index....`

Comment: I added the line and it doesn't produce anything different then what i've been shown and i added the html form

Comment: Consult my answer below. @xcred and sorry about earlier. It's always best to post your entire code when posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the form not processing correctly, is that you are using POST variables.

Your form is missing `post` for its method. `<form>` defaults to GET if it's not specified.

Change:

```
<form action="" id="contactform">
```

to

```
<form action="" id="contactform" method="post">
```

and it will work.

Comment: Still receiving the "Sorry, we can't send this message."

Comment: @xcred OK, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @xcred Q: Is your entire code on the one page, meaning the code that sends the mail and the form? Or, are you using 2 seperate files for them?

Comment: 2 seperate files ones contact.php and ones config.php and the HTML form is in my main index.html

Comment: @xcred Change `<form action=""` to `<form action="contact.php"` then. Full line `<form action="contact.php" id="contactform" method="post">`

Comment: @xcred I don't know what else it could be then. I've tested all of this on my server. Your code checks out, far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I finally Solved it! thanks you were always right. I realized that namecheap(domain host) won't allow relaying to my gmail account so they would send but to my cpanel email. THANKS!

Comment: @xcred That's great, and thanks for the update, glad it got resolved. If you want to tick that checkmark next to my question till it turns green, it will close the question properly and be marked as solved. *Cheers* - You're very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bought this template, you wouldn't have to ask your question here. Please ask the creator of the Zwin - Responsive Vcard Template next time. He will help you out.